# How do I customise a Devise helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user management. I need to run some custom code defining where the user is redirected to after they sign in. I've found the [after_sign_in_path_for](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in_and_redirect-instance_method) method, which I think is what I need to use. But I'm not sure how to use it. Where do I put my custom after_sign_in_path_for method to override the default one? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

this one looks handy, didn't know about it.

```
 sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
```

I cannot get block quote to work so I will just but what the api says below

Sign in an user and tries to redirect first to the stored location and then to the url specified by after_sign_in_path_for. It accepts the same parameters as the sign_in method.

I take this to mean that you pass the path as the second argument and this will override the default root path

for example

```
 sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, posts_path)
```

so that would take you to `:controller => "post", :action => "index"`

Comment: I tried putting a path in there, but I get an error. I've edited the original question with the details. Thanks for your help.